# Why have tag gold badge recipients been given the dupe-hammer but not an MCVE-hammer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I find the dupe-hammer privilege to be somewhat difficult to use on the tags I look at.  I think it's a dupe, so I go searching for an appropriate dupe.  The process gets to be fairly tedious with searching and reviewing other questions.  There seems to me to be a lot of gray area.  Maybe the answer is the same but the question is slightly different.  Maybe the question is really two questions, one of which is a dupe.  Maybe...  So it's a privilege that I use occasionally, but perhaps not enough.  Many times it's just easier to jot off an answer than to go on the hunt.  I don't feel like it's a particularly useful tool at improving the signal-to-noise ratio.

But it's undoubtedly a codified and legitimate close reason, when used properly.

We have this other close reason that [questions seeking debugging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) need to have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (the word *must* is used, that seems pretty unequivocal).

I can immediately identify a question that I think is asking for debugging help.  Furthermore, it's usually a trivial matter, requiring no searching at all, to determine whether or not it has an MCVE, which is [pretty well defined](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In other words, I think an MCVE hammer would:

1. be easier for me to use
2. permit me a higher confidence level that when I used it, I was justified
3. be a more effective tool at improvement of signal to noise

So why do we have one but not the other?

- Is it that we don't really want the MCVE close reason to be used more extensively than it is now?
- Or maybe we think, in spite of my opinion, that it's a fundamentally harder decision to make than a dupe?
- Or maybe, we're just not serious about expecting an MCVE on these types of questions?
- Or dupes are a *much much* bigger problem than MCVE questions (that's not my opinion, and I think my voting record underscores my opinion, but then I don't really focus on the c++ tag, for example.  Maybe they are awash in dupes.)

I believe that I could use such a tool with a higher confidence level (easier to justify my usage), more frequently, with a better net effect on SNR, than the dupe hammer.

Regarding the impact that marking a dupe has on the OP, probably little (in terms of conditioning them to write better questions.)  They got their answer, and conveniently enough, someone else did the searching for them.

An MCVE closure does just the opposite: the OP *does not get* what they came looking for.  Instead they are immediately faced with the prospect that "if I want an answer, I'm going to have to improve my question".  That strikes me as better conditioning (for future questions) and better learning (for the OP).

As I indicated already, I'm kinda lazy about finding dupes, but if you're feeling a bit ironical, maybe [my question is a dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no).  Hammer away.  It's my first meta question, so it's just karma that it should be closed anyway.

Comment: Short answer: it's easier for 3rd-parties (other users) to verify that duplicates are being closed correctly.

Comment: [This particular question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270829/1079354) doesn't duplicate your own, but it discusses adding the privilege for gold badge holders.

Comment: I would think that for the same reasons that I find a missing MCVE easier to identify, it would be easier for other users to identify (verify) the same thing as well.  Again, MCVE is pretty well spelled out.  If your code won't compile, it's probably not an MCVE (assuming your request for debug help isn't about a compile issue.)  These things strike me as pretty easy to identify.

Comment: @Makoto I agree.  Anything would be better than what we have now.  I guess it takes 5 close votes.  So 1,2,3 or 4 is better than 5.  I've previously suggested in comments that I think close vote count requirements should be scaled to the traffic on the tag (or the traffic that is associated with the highest traffic tag currently on the question.)  `c++` - 5 close votes.  `bonobo` - 2 close votes, or similar.

Comment: I would point out that the dup hammer is system wide (IIRC). And duplicate is part of the system wide close reasons. MCVE is a custom tag. You might want to consider tweaking this into a feature request of "allow mods to mark specific custom close reasons with (gold|silver|bronze) badge counts as [54321] close votes".  This allows for a better, system wide, abstraction of the effort that is likely more in line with the existing functionality and goals.

Comment: I'd be wary of extending too much power to gold badge holders. I'm cautious about wielding Mjölnir, and while I'd like to be able to delete negative voted answers (where the total negative votes doesn't include my down-vote), I've not seen that many questions where I'd want to close it for lack of an MCVE. That may just be the circles I move in; other people's experience is probably different. But be cautious about extending it. Or, give people with the gold badge the option to submit a regular vote instead of always wielding Mjölnir.  (Have Mjölnir as the default, but not the only option.)

Comment: As stated, the MCVE close reason is more subjective than a dupe. Personally, I would prefer to see focus put on making the reason description more objective and broader. Too often, a question really needs a MCVE, even though it's not necessarily "debugging help" per se. This is alluded to in the second half of the description (_"without a clear problem statement"_), but there are still bad questions left unclosed because people focus on the first half. Lacking a non-"Other" choice that really fits (for them), they don't vote "close" (though they may in fact down-vote the question).

Comment: I like the idea of tightening up the MCVE close reason - because I think it makes my proposal even more of a slam-dunk.  But I don't know how to do it because I don't know every programming language.  For the ones I have some familiarity in, (C, C++, Fortran) I think a reasonable statement is that (excepting compile issues) "I should be able to copy, paste, compile, and run the code, without having to add anything or change anything, and see the issue being reported." (Again, assuming it's not a *compile* issue - but that is a trivial extension to the statement.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262863/close-as-dupe-when-there-is-no-effort-shown

Answer (score 12):

I would not endorse giving similar power to gold badge holders for any other close reason other than duplicate (perhaps having more weight than a normal user, but not the full power Mjölnir exercises over duplicates).

First of all, **questions are almost always objectively duplicates or objectively not**. The duplicate close reason is probably the *least* abusable reason available. Yes, sometimes questions are accidentally closed as duplicates, but that's a very rare case, and usually such cases are due to a simple misunderstanding. Those questions get reopened fairly quickly.

This is especially problematic because of users' tendencies to use close votes as a Super Downvote™. If a question is poorly-researched, people look to close them. This isn't *always* a bad thing, and indeed, downvoting and closing probably correlate fairly strongly. That said, there are lots of questions that deserve to be downvoted without being closed and vice-versa.

The duplicate close reason is unique in that sense because high-quality duplicates are actually frequently *upvoted*. [One of my highest-scoring questions was closed as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21962641/465378), but because it was a good question that was not frequently asked (and the duplicate was not easy to find), it ended up getting a good score. Once the dupe was tracked down, it was closed (and I voted to close it, too).

The duplicate close reason really is different from the others due to its scope and how it's applied. It's pretty much impossible to it to be abused, so expediting the process makes sense.

Second of all, **gold badge holders are actually more qualified to handle duplicates than non-badge holders**. Presumably, these people have spent quite a bit of time in a given tag, and they're well-aware about what questions are out there. I don't think this argument really holds for any of the other close reasons. A gold badge holder will be able to recognize an off-topic question just as easily as a silver, or even a bronze, badge holder.

It might make sense to increase close vote weight somewhat, but I don't think *gold badges* make sense as the criteria to enable that. Perhaps [it should be a 30k privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252690/188673). Maybe for [silver badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/188673)? Even then, it should probably only be an increase in weight, not an insta-close power.

Gold badges indicate people are **knowledgable about the topic in question**, but they don't necessarily qualify them as superior moderators. We have the moderator elections and reputation system for that. I agree that those could be improved in various ways, but this isn't the right approach to take.

Comment: Regarding this statement: "Gold badges ... don't necessarily qualify them as superior moderators."  There have been about 4k tag gold badges awarded in total.  I suspect if you reviewed these, nearly all would be to people who *also* had a pretty high reputation, and SO *does* equate high rep with superior (community) moderation skills.  So I claim there is a correlation between gold tag badge and superior moderation skills.

Comment: Regarding the characteristics of dupe vs. MCVE, I claim (without proof) that I can more easily spot a question lacking an MCVE than a dupe.  My question/proposal actually hinges on that concept.  But you're not alone in expressing disagreement - other comments below the question also basically suggest disagreement.  I can agree that if we don't trust our gold tag badge owners, then we definitely should not extend this privilege.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I don't disagree that, in general, spotting a MVCE question is *much* easier than finding a dupe. I actually think that's the problem. It just opens the ability for abuse.

Comment: What's the opening for abuse given that it is so easy to Verify?

Comment: My experience has been that there's no actual agreement between SO users (who read/post on meta) about what factors determine whether a post is a duplicate, so I can't agree that posts are objectively duplicates or not.

Comment: While researching, I came across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) which lists the number of gold tag badges awarded by tag (for non-zero cases).  Depending on which tag, the number might be smaller than you think.  Even for a relatively large one like `c#`, it is still less than 1% of those following the tag.  I looked at several others, and the gold tag badge ownership seems to be generally less than 1% of those following the tag.  Figuring out average rep of those holders seems more difficult, but for one tag I looked at (2 holders) the rep of each was >40k.

Answer (score 4):

The very fact it takes a lot of work to find a duplicate is one of the reasons why making it easier to do is worthwhile.  With the Mjolnir you have awesome cosmic power -- but in exchange for using it, you must provide proof that you found another question whose answers answer this one.

If you fail to find another question whose answers answer this one, disputing it is easy (namely, the other answers does not answer the question above!) and tends not to be as opinion based as other close reasons might be.

Duplicate is arguably the hardest close reason, as you actually have to find a duplicate.  The other close reasons, you just have to find other people who agree: with duplicate, you have to provide proof that it is a duplicate.  If Duplicate was like the other close reasons, you would just have to say "this is a duplicate of something on the site, go find it yourself".

The very difficulty of closing something as a "good" duplicate is why it should be "rewarded" with phenomenal cosmic power (if insufficient square footage), together with the fact that the effort provides a proof to others that your close is valid (so errors can be corrected).

When someone solves an NP problem, we shouldn't take it lightly.

Comment: So, it doesn't matter whether making it easier to close for any other reason is worthwhile on its own merits, as long as closing duplicates is unavoidably so much harder?

Comment: @dedup naw: if other close reasons had a strong proof of work component (that was way easier to invalidate than to generate), I would say hammer upgrade is fine.  It is the ease of proving duplicate wrong that makes me think Mjolnir is good.  Plus, making duplicate easier rewards the required work (in that it happens, instead of being queued).

Answer (score 1):

My experience flagging a couple hundred MCVEs and probably less than a hundred dupes has been that the dupes are far more contentious and far subtler than MCVEs in all but one subarea: the M. I have never yet seen anyone make any significant reduction in posted code after I mentioned that it looked like they had too much and flagged as MCVE, and an awful lot flat-out disagree that it's possible to reduce any further, even if they have 500 lines with lots of comments.

So while I would love to encourage faster MCVEing, it's that first letter that seems dubious enough to make the thing unpopular and tricky to manage. Maybe gold badgers have enough weight to make it stick. But it usually doesn't take a gold badge to get the other three letters figured out.

Comment: M is a judgement call.  If the code is complete, compilable, and demonstrates the issue, I don't think I would *ever* flag just based on the M. (although I might ask if a reduction is possible.)  I'm willing to tackle 500 lines sometimes.  I get tired of questions with no code at all, code that doesn't compile, code that's obviously incomplete.  Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610705/cudamalloc-of-2d-array).  I consider anyone who has provided a CVE as a shining example for the rest.  Here's a [CVE example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606225).  (I didn't flag it.)