# Would it be useful to have an extension of mjölnir close voting powers for (language) tag related close reasons?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, dupehammer

Inspired from [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326227/i-should-be-allowed-to-answer-closed-questions) and my [comment at Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326227/i-should-be-allowed-to-answer-closed-questions#comment357842_326232), I'm going to ask for that feature now:

**I'd like to see an extension for the gold badge users of a particular tag, not only to be able to single-handedly close questions (aka the *mighty mjölnir*) as a [duplicate] but also for the close reasons that specifically rely on details of the (language) tag and knowledge about it.**

In particular, I see the close vote reasons

> - Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
> - This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Maybe for any close reason appearing at the **off-topic because ...** second level of detail, besides the custom and other side appliance close reasons, to be appropriate to be used single-handedly by a gold badge tag owner and level of trustworthiness.

---

I think such a feature could greatly improve to bail out VLQ questions for particular tags early, and reduce the overall noise.

I'm mostly trusting my peers, and if I have resilient doubts, I should be able to revert such a decision single-handedly as well (or it needs to get into the reopen queue as usual).

The power would be just to **show stop** any questions, that miss efforts to debug the tag-related errors with the obviously available tools (including Google, Bing, Yahoo answers, etc.).

---

Taking on from [walfrat's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326250/would-it-be-useful-to-have-an-extension-of-mj%c3%b6lnir-close-voting-powers-for-lang?cb=1#comment358059_326250), as I have mentioned missing efforts, it might need a certain condition as e.g. a threshold of downvotes, or question score (like there is for delete votes) to enable using the feature.

---

There's also this positively accepted [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319399/closing-questions-with-typos-faster-typo-hammer) brought by [dasblinkenlight](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) (who's certainly a *trusted user*) which goes closely along with mine.

Comment: Can we add too broad to the list?

Comment: Actually, the 2 you mentioned I see are the most misused close reasons on the site, although I can't corrolate the misuse I've seen with gold badge holders.  But regardless it should be all of none. I have a feeling users would pick the wrong close reason just to close the question. Better to just give them everything

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tagged [tag:discussion] so I'm open.

Comment: @psubsee2003 _"Better to just give them everything "_ I'm afraid that's too much of powers. _"Actually, the 2 you mentioned I see are the most misused close reasons on the site"_ can you point out any examples for _evidence_ where these close resons are _misused_ actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `I'm afraid that's too much of powers` but that's the point.  Some (not all) users feel a question needs to be closed ASAP, so they will use the one that will give the insta-close powers instead of the more appropriate one.  I have a pet peeve for wrong close reasons because they end up failing the original poster by not providing accurate feedback.  I think letting the gold badge users choose the most appropriate reason is better than only giving them selective powers because there is less chance for abuse.  Either we trust them to do it right or we don't.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ as for the proof of misuse, I'm afraid I don't have an examples handy.  My comment on that was just observational.  But it is not uncommon to see posts as "seeking debugging" without any code at all.  I see less issues with typos, but I have seen common syntax error questions that can be made useful (and searchable) to get closed as typos.  Like i said originally, none of these may be gold badge holders doing it, and they would do it correctly.  But I felt it was worth mentioning.

Comment: *Very* closely related but not *quite* a dupe (but I'd say it's pretty close!):  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270829/1079354

Comment: @psubsee2003: "*I have seen common syntax error questions that can be made useful (and searchable) to get closed as typos.*" Are they actually typos? Because the most common syntax errors I get are typos. It's one thing if someone is clearly inventing a reason to close. It's quite another if you two simply disagree on whether a typo is really a typo.

Comment: @NicolBolas a syntax error is not a typo for someone who doesn't understand the syntax.  A typo is when I make a mistake typing.  When I make a mistake writing code because I don't know the "rules", I don't see how that can be a typo.  These types of issues can be tough to search for, so they are usually not good SO questions, but for the ones that can be made searchable, closing them just because you think it is a typo seems to be a waste of an opportunity.

Comment: @psubsee2003: "*a syntax error is not a typo for someone who doesn't understand the syntax.*" The reader of a question should not make close voting decisions based on the apparent skill level of the person asking the question. You vote based on the *content* of the question; nothing more. And if the content would be a typo from a 20k user, then it's a typo from a 1-rep user. Remember: we're not here to help the OP; we're here to help other people too.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290006). This has been brought up before, without success. My suggestion is that gold badge close votes should be given more weight (i.e. worth 2 votes) when applied to the MCVE close reason.

Comment: @NicolBolas i don't think we'll agree on this.  I agree that we are not here to help just the OP, but that's where we differ.  Common syntax problems that **can be made searchable** will help others.  But just others who are new to a language and are not familiar with the syntax.  Why are other "basic" questions that are well asked acceptable but syntax errors need to be closed because someone who knows the language would know it is a typo.

Comment: FWIW, the typo questions can be handled with the dupe hammer, given that  all of the common typos have been asked and answered a hundred times. If there isn't a good dupe for a particular typo, you can always make a canonical Q&A for that, and then hammer away.

Comment: I completely agree with the second criteria. I agree with the first but you would never get it implemented. I'd love to be able to nuke crappy questions in a few categories; especially those that simply reek of *'I want someone to do my work for me.'*

Comment: Why is a gold badge required to identify a question as not meeting MCVE requirements, or being off-topic? If we're going to start giving individuals the power to close questions for reasons that don't require an expertise in the tag it would make more sense for it to be based on overall rep or even just length of time on the site.

Comment: @JonathanPotter without the knowledge of the technology, you might not know if the question can  be just resolved with a google/SO search or not. Or worst, think it's an easy and lazy question when it's not really one.

Comment: If it seems to much of power for one gold tag user, maybe we could have a little restriction, like having 5 downvotes on the question ?

Comment: I believe the technical term for what you are proposing is "pissing in the wind". There is simply too much ingrained skepticism on the part of some of the trustworthiness and judgment of gold badge holders. These people would rather see the site drown in fecal matter, and the experienced users flee the site, than speed up the closing of questions. We've been over this territory so often that it makes my head spin. We can keep discussing it until the cows come home. Someone needs to step up and make a policy decision, but I don't even know who that would be.

Comment: @Walfrat _"like having 5 downvotes on the question ?"_ I like that idea, since it still involves some democratic consensus that it's a bad question and should be closed.

Comment: @tora Maybe we could call Jeff Atwood and have him settle it?

Comment: @Walfrat You are fundamentally confused about the difference in meaning between downvotes and closevotes.

Comment: @torazaburo I do know that downvotes are not closevotes. However what i was thinking is that having 5 close votes may take more time than having 5 downvotes, whatever the reason is for thoses. This final decision is still in the hand of one gold tag owner but with the fact that the community disapprouve this post. I tihnk the number 5 of downvotes is fair because : 1- I don't think it's so common to have -5+ question which donot hve a problem with the rules. 2 There is still the gold tag owner which we expect a better judgement. 3 There is still the reopen queue.

Comment: @Walfrat A question might deserve to be closed, for one of the specific reasons provided, none of which would justify a downvote. A question might be downvoted into oblivion, without any close reason being applicable. It's real important to distinguish between the two, and not conflate them into some murky "bad question" concept. Whether a question should be closed has nothing to do with how many upvotes or downvotes it has. It is closed for a specific close reason. The only question is, how many of what kind of people need to vote to close for which of those reasons.

Comment: @torazaburo This is what the gold tag owner would be torazaburo. And even following your point, the question may not be how many, but can we trust more some people so their vote weight better and get post closed faster then. Instead of gold badges, we could have a privilege related to those who actively participate to closing review queue. Along with the fact that the system don't allow you to spam the review blindly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well, _too broad_ questions moslty aren't directly related to a background knowledge of a specific language or tag.

Comment: ***This long list of comments and discussion should be continued with some answers now.***

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'd be glad to see your counter points summarized in an answer.

Comment: I'd rather have the option to sometimes disable  (as in *not use*) my extra *closing powers* instead of extending them. More often than I would like, I have voted *duplicate*, where I would have liked to see the confirmation of others voting the same. But instead, because of my *powers*, the question was insta-closed. Because of this, I find myself waiting for other close-votes first, instead of taking initial action.

Comment: @Yoshi I'm writing the comment by hand in such cases. It's often enough working well, that 5 others or another gold badge holder agrees.

Answer (score 47):

**Of the 5,372,568 users at Stack Overflow, there are only 3,058 users with gold tag badges**

I think expansion is a good idea, because [*that was the original idea*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/178816). I remember well, I authored it. It all started from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252616/1026459) (in case you want to follow a lot of the discussion with regards to increased weight overall, and not just for duplicates which was the outcome then).

> First, if we're gonna do this then let's make it worthwhile: 1 vote == closed, regardless of how many other votes or flags are in play. -[Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230882/178816)

At the time of suggesting (May, 2014) the increased closure weight, Shog9 provided a set of statistics that perhaps everyone is not aware of so I will reproduce them here.

> So... *What if* we had silently implemented this on Stack Overflow a year ago, and no one had altered their behavior...
>
> - **22,102** questions currently open with pending close votes would instead be closed.
> - **145,843** questions currently closed would have been closed *faster* and with less effort needed from other voters. 90,722 of these would have been closed with a single vote.
> - **34,837** questions currently open would have been closed instead of the vote aging away. Note that 11,677 of these went through review and were marked "Leave Open".
> - **2,677** questions would have been closed faster, but then reopened anyway.
> - **1,328** questions would have been *reopened* faster
> - **1,837** questions would have been reopened instead of the vote aging away. Note that 1,829 of these went through review and were marked "Leave Closed".
> - **1,071** questions would have been re-opened faster, but then closed again.

These statistics, although slightly dated, were composed through the lens of increasing weight *to all closure votes*. As is seen there is a clear advantage to faster closure with this process. As a result it would **save time** of users who should be answering and creating content instead of casting close votes; while it may not be immediately obvious, there is a cost to casting close votes and that does add up over time. Increasing the vote weight would offset that cost.

Furthermore, when officially acknowledging the dupehammer being implemented, [Tim Post remarked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/178816)

> We're doing this for duplicates only to start, because it's incredibly silly not to do this. Not giving people with gold tag badges more abilities in their tags is just wasting some very valuable signal

Which is a clear indication that the dupehammer was *just the start* of an experiment which at this point has clearly panned out. There has not been any of the widespread abuse people feared. Tim goes on to state

> This is being deployed initially as an experiment, I think there's enough sanity here to prevent most abuse cases, and we don't really have a very large rate of incorrect duplicates. If this pans out well, we might consider giving gold tag badge holders more weight in other areas

tl;dr; I fully support the expansion of close vote weight for gold tag badge holders. It was originally intended to be expanded, as shown. I don't think it should be limited to a subset of reasons. I understand that maybe just starting with a subset would be a good way to slowly roll this out and test. However, perhaps that would just force users into choosing the wrong close reasons for questions which should clearly be closed.

Comment: You have a point, I didn't realize we were so few. I'll do my best to be constructive about this. In a nutshell, I believe this situation gives us a legitimacy that may not be apparent to the lambda user (less apparent than a moderator's, in any case). For this to succeed, we should devise a way to convey this legitimacy to the lambda user. Mjölnir does that with a badge marker and a tooltip, and it's working quite well. However, it may be harder to generalize that message to all close reasons IMHO. We have to be careful about the signal we would be sending.

Comment: _"it would save time of users who should be answering and creating content instead of casting close votes; while it may not be immediately obvious, there is a cost to casting close votes"_ -- I agree 100% with this assertion, and it's a source of great frustration for me. It's just that authoritarianism is a sharp blade to be wielded carefully and judiciously. I feel that the "as duplicate" vote has clearly different characteristics from other close reasons, characteristics which easily mitigate what would otherwise create contentiousness in the community, as other close reasons would.

Comment: It is not authoritarianism. Closure is not a permanent state. An individual police officer has broad jurisdiction to arrest you if he feels it is justified. That doesn't make it an authoritarian state; you still have rights. Namely, the right to habeas corpus. Our equivalent would be the Reopen Vote queue and auditing by other community members who happen by. We also have the option of flagging a moderator directly and asking them to *instantly* override the decision of the close-voter. In other words, I don't get all the hand-wringing about the possibility for abuse.

Comment: @Cody: I am less worried about actual abuse, than I am about _perceived_ abuse. The former is not good, but as you point out less likely and has a mechanism, albeit not necessarily discoverable to the neophyte, for appeal. The latter is just straight-up corrosive to the cohesiveness of the community. In some cases, it's worth risking that because the benefit is so great. But I'm just not seeing the scales tip that way here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes, the abuse of badly answering bad and straight off-topic questions is too great.

Comment: From [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/501947) there are (from when this data was created, so slightly out of date) 5,418 gold tag badges spread around 3,058 unique users.

Comment: @Deduplicator: do you know of any source where your thesis is represented in an objective form supported by data? (for those of us; who less moved by emotional appeals) Shog9's posts could used as examples.

Answer (score 16):

This answer is to address a specific point in @Peter Duniho's answer.

> Second, and IMHO most important, when a question is closed as a duplicate, the author of the question actually receives real help.

When I see a question that's missing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's in the *question author's best interest* that their question is closed as quickly as possible.

This might sound counterintuitive, so let me explain.

When a question/issue can't be reproduced there is a tendency for anyone who views the question to downvote it and leave (because many users can't or won't vote).

The asker is then burdened by what are essentially undue downvotes the longer their question remains open. If I can instantly vote-close a question, the asker knows exactly who to have a discussion with once they've made the appropriate updates.

If the asker has received 4 or 5 downvotes, there's a much lower chance that they're going to be willing to try to fix their own post, because it'll take more effort to revert those votes just to be positive.

This puts the asker in a better place to make changes to their question and have it reopened.

Comment: That is a really good point. Often when I find a question that is problematic I have tried to engage with the OP only to find no response. Increased attentiveness as a side effect here would be a massive advantage.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, OK, but let's go further.**

No doubt the close review queue is too big and it's very ineffective to close questions (the few and brave people that review scatter their votes around on different questions and this makes their work just age away).

SE certainly needs to address this problem sooner or later if they still want to keep the feature that questions can/should be closed (I guess SE is currently mostly relying on the roomba for the clean-up effort).

I understand that gold badgers like to close and reopen as they please, and this would be OK for me but I really do not think this will solve the problem. Do the gold badgers today already close all duplicate questions? Or are there only a few that put their effort into finding duplicates and closing them?

Furthermore, in low-traffic tags there are no or very few gold badges and flagging or close voting questions in these tags is fairly hopeless.

In my opinion SO needs to address this problem in a much wider way not only using gold badgers.

I have no direct solution today but I have seen many different suggestions, such as close vote weight depending on tag badges (I think the basic idea was from Tunaki). For example

```
Gold badge   - 1 cv, counts as 4 cv
Silver badge - 1 cv, counts as 3 cv
Bronze badge - 1 cv, counts as 2 cv
```

and probably this should be scaled depending on traffic in tags.

So my 2 cents to your request is:

SE needs to address this problem in a much wider way than just relying on gold hammers, creating commitment and involvement from the whole community, probably re-thinking what is needed to close a question and how the close review queue filters and displays questions.

Comment: Weights for close votes is also an interesting idea, though these should be restricted to the tag relevant close reasons.

Answer (score 6):

I really want to support this idea. I really do. I hate all the bad questions that show up, and I hate the number of other people who will jump to attempt to answer the bad questions, on the off-chance that they might get some up-votes, even when they aren't even really sure what the question is, and I hate the people who *do* up-vote such answers, not because the answer addresses the question per se, but because it's a good answer to *some* question.

The faster we could close questions that lead to these outcomes, the better.

But I think there are a couple of fundamental differences in the close reasons that strongly argue to preserve the gold badge privilege as it is today.

First, closing as duplicate is about as close to a purely objective close reason as one can get, and requires that the person closing the post make some genuine effort to document and justify their decision. Even there, people whine. They argue that their question isn't a duplicate, only because they aren't proficient enough to understand why they do have fundamentally the same problem and do need exactly the same resolution to their problem, as is found in the duplicate target. But the duplicate is right there in black & white for all to see. And if it's not a duplicate, that will be obvious as well, and the community can quickly reverse the mistaken closure.

Second, and IMHO most important, when a question is closed as a duplicate, **the author of the question actually receives real help**. To me, this is a critical element in the balancing of the powers of the gold badge holder. Closing the question not only improves the quality of the site, but it also produces a positive result for the author of the question.

Other close reasons are really just rejections. Do we trust gold badge holders? Yes, of course. But we should be very careful when we exercise outright rejection. Rejections hurt, no matter how much one might rightly argue that one should take constructive criticism in stride. Requiring plural support from the community helps validate such rejections, makes sure that rejections are well-deserved, and reinforces the message such rejection might send to the author of the post.

It's very easy to ignore the opinion of one person, even if they have the gold badge. It's a lot harder when five or more people have expressed the same opinion.

By restricting the single-handed closure power to the close reason that is reasonably objective and especially to the one that can actually **help** the author of the post solves their problem, we will minimize the fallout that would otherwise occur from the closure of a person's question, while at the same time helping to keep the basic community mood on the positive side by minimizing the amount of direct one-on-one conflict.

So, I have to say, my vote is "no" on this idea. As much as I want to have more freedom to help get rid of the bad questions, I think there are strong reasons to continue to restrict the gold badge privilege as it is today.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, even if your final conclusion goes against my proposal. Discussion and arguing in depth about such feature was what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, I have chosen these two close reasons mentioned in my question carefully (as being directly related to the knowledge coming from the trusted gold badge background). While the 2nd close reason usually will be effective quickly (just my observations), the 1st one often takes too long, or some fool chimes in to debug e.g. a fully flegded code dump of more than a 1000 lines and actually finds the error. They'll get upvotes, an accept mark probably, and prevent that crap question from being deleted automatically. Good job, that's not useful for anyone than the OP and the answerer.

Comment: Also: _"**the author of the question actually receives real help**"_, Doesn't enforcing them to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help actually? Most of such problems could be identified and fixed when doing so.

Comment: Oh, already two downvotes up to now. Looks like the community loves my proposal. Though don't be discouraged, stand your opinions (that stuff is exactly what I have doubts for and hesitated to ask for that feature earlier).

Comment: Well, what about at least making gold-badgers count simply count more?

Comment: Meh. A moderator named CasperOne used to camp the newest page and single vote close off topic questions all the time. It was great. All it did was allow users with genuine questions more of an opportunity to get their question answered by someone actually taking their time. 5 Gold Tag badge users voting to close a question from a 1 reputation user that has a -6 score is a freaking awful waste of time; the cost of those close votes is very high at that point.

Comment: Related to the point in your final sentence, there, @TravisJ: [Should a question with a significant negative score be automatically closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251454) and [Reduce the close vote threshold when the question is heavily downvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234231)

Comment: @Travis, that's an excellent example. Why is Casper not a moderator anymore? Why are they far less active on Meta than they used to be? Why were they the first (and almost only) moderator I regularly saw taking tremendous amounts of flak from everywhere at once? Their diamond did not protect them. Us gold badge holders don't even have one.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - You seem to be implying causation with my example yet cite no reference. Why is that? *Their diamond did not protect them*? From what exactly? What do gold tag badge holders need protection from? I think you are attacking a straw man here.

Comment: @Travis, yup, I'm implying causation. Maybe I was not clear enough -- at one point CasperOne was routinely singled out amongst moderators *because he (I think he's a guy) camped the newest questions page and one-handedly closed all the crap he found there*. He was a moderator, with all the legitimacy to do that, yet there was a lot of blood and tears because people just threw that legitimacy out of the window. There is even [a Quora article with his name on it](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-casperOne-close-ALL-of-the-best-questions-on-Stack-Overflow). Gold badge holders would not last a week.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - One Quora post with 7 SO post links and an answer stating that the posts should have been closed is not exactly supporting your argument. This reads more as fear mongering than actual evidence, especially your claim that Gold badge holders would somehow not last a week. Where is the evidence for that?

Comment: Fear mongering? Wow. Okay, you win, go ahead with this feature if you want. I was only reminiscing things you may not have noticed back then, but I can't spend my evening hunting for the last remaining "evidence" on the Overmeta. If this feature is implemented, time will have to tell (but don't say I didn't warn you :)

Comment: @π: _"I have chosen these two close reasons mentioned in my question carefully"_ -- I understand. But they require no supporting documentation as the duplicate vote does, and I agree with the concerns voiced by others than there will be some who select those close reasons just because they want the question closed for _some_ reason, and those are what's available, not because they are actually the reason for closing the question. MCVE is a particularly fraught reason because, while I personally want to see a good MCVE on every question, I have to admit some questions, including those that...

Comment: @π: ...really shouldn't have been posted in the first place (often because they are too basic) can be adequately answered without one. It is most often my opinion these questions should be closed due to poor quality, but there's ample evidence many others disagree. Most moderators answer to the community, through the democratic selection process. Gold badge holders closing questions that could be answered but which shouldn't be on the site are just going to lead to intra-community disputes. _"Doesn't enforcing them to create a MCVE help actually?"_ -- only if the question cannot be answered...

Comment: @π: ...any other way. You can still help by just writing a comment suggesting they provide one, and the community as a whole is in a better position to judge whether the MCVE is _required_. If you single-handedly close the question, that prevents anyone else from providing an answer in spite of the lack of the MCVE, which harms the author of the question rather than helping them. I hope I've made clear my ambivalence on the topic; I very much would love to have stronger powers to kill questions I deem bad. It's just that one of the things that makes SO such a positive place is that...

Comment: @π: ...standards are mostly decided on and judged by the community, rather than a small number of anointed individuals. I strongly suspect the proposed change would harm that dynamic. _"Looks like the community loves my proposal"_ -- careful. Some people (perhaps many) will upvote your question because it's well-presented and a good issue to discuss, not necessarily because they agree with the proposal itself. I have good reason to believe you're familiar with this particular effect. :)

Comment: I see your point, but I respectfully disagree with it.  We don't wish to clutter the site up with questions that are nothing more than "it doesn't work" or "why doesn't this work" when they miss a fairy obvious semicolon that any self-respecting compiler/interpreter would catch.

Comment: @Makoto: are those really the questions that are cluttering up the site? I don't think so. Yes, they show up, but syntax errors are the least of our problems. I, for one, would like to see a current analysis similar to that presented by Travis in his answer. Even accounting for the age of the analysis, I don't see a strong potential for percentage-wise improvement in the closure rate. We're talking tens of thousands of questions, out of literally tens of **millions**. At the very least, the proposal deserves a factually-based argument in favor, which I haven't seen yet.

Comment: Ah, I see you haven't seen the raw, unfiltered Android tags.  Or PHP.  Or Java.  Or C#.  I mean, those sorts of questions are asked *all the time*, and while anecdotally it's not comforting to hear it just off the cuff, most anyone who's spent some time in those question tags would understand.  It isn't a huge amount, but we as professionals need to draw a line in the sand someplace.

Comment: @Makoto: I spend all of my SO time with the C# tag; it's the only tag I have a gold badge for. Typos just aren't a problem; they don't make up the bulk of new questions or even a significant fraction of them, and those that do appear are closed quickly enough with community support. If you want to argue to the contrary, in support of this proposal, I'd suggest you get out some real data and post an answer with the numbers that support your assertions.

Comment: @Frédéric Wow, that's a good point. I had completely forgotten about the plight of poor CasperOne. I was around for that, when he was called out *at least* once a week on Meta for being tyrannical or some such nonsense. I guess no one wants to stand against all that pressure for very long. As far as this happening to gold tag-badge holders, I think the effect would be much diminished just because of sheer volume. It wouldn't be the same guy with his name attached to all the closed questions, which would take away the air of suspicion. All close-voters take ire, but you can't fix that.

Comment: @Cody: _"It wouldn't be the same guy"_ -- wouldn't it? I mean, sure it's unlikely it'd literally just only be one person. But it's just as likely that there'd be just a handful of gold badgers responsible for the bulk of the single-handed closures. The weight would fall disproportionately on those few people. _"All close-voters take ire, but you can't fix that"_ -- it seems to me you can, as I've described in my answer here. I.e. by ensuring the bulk of closures happen as a community effort, it's a lot harder for the question author to take offense. It will still happen, but much less often.

Comment: I just don't agree with that part of your answer, then. The bulk of closures *now* happen by community effort, but we get *tons* of "questions" on Meta from people who complain that their question was closed by a gang of 5 petty tyrants. Having 4 other people's names up there doesn't really shield you from much abuse or criticism. And that's only the criticism that people have the intestinal fortitude to post here on Meta. There's tons more shade being thrown around about us close-voters and moderators on other sites, like Reddit and people's personal blogs.

Comment: Elsewhere you said that you aren't sure you can get behind this because you aren't convinced the risk is worth the reward. I am shocked that you can say that. Even if I admit to some of the risk, you have to admit that the number of eligible close voters *vastly* outstrips the number of off-topic and low-quality questions that get posted to this site. We are outnumbered by a ratio of more than 5, so requiring 5 votes each time is just not practical. The site is being overrun, and we absolutely have to do something (cf. other Meta discussions about this). This seems like a workable plan.

Comment: @Cody: you're welcome to your opinion. IMHO, the onus is on the proposal to be justified by data. You say _"we get tons of "questions" on Meta from people who complain"_, but SO also closes "tons" of questions. What proportion of those are generating complaints? And regardless, how does that not prove the point? Don't you believe there would be an intensification of that effect if the closures were single-handed?

Comment: @Cody: _"The site is being overrun"_ -- yes, but at least in the C# tag, this is more due to bad _upvoting_; as you already pointed out, a single-handed close vote can be overruled by the mob. Begin "outnumbered" is a red herring. You don't need five different people for each different question; the same gang of five could just as easily perform the moderation tasks, if the motivation was actually there (join the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room if you want to participate in that).

Comment: @PeterDuniho - While dated, I am not sure if you are properly interpreting the statistics there. You state *Even accounting for the age of the analysis, I don't see a strong potential for percentage-wise improvement in the closure rate.*, however a whopping **40% of closure would have happened with 1 vote instead of 5 votes**. To me, that is a massive improvement.

Comment: @TravisJ 40% with 1 vote of one gold tag owner ? Or anyone ? Because if it's just anyone, quite some of those closure wouldn't have been right.

Comment: @TravisJ: First of all, the stats you posted aren't relevant any more, because **we solved that problem**. I.e. gold badgers are now closing those posts. Further, I don't find the comparison between two different closure scenarios to be that compelling. I mean, sure...it'd be nice to have. But the posts get closed either way.

Comment: @TravisJ: To me, the important question is to compare the number of posts that were closed for any reason with the additional number of unclosed posts that would have been closed by that single vote. Even the out-of-date stats show only about a 10% improvement (~40K out of ~400K). So now that gold badgers _are_ closing posts single-handedly, what do those stats look like today, when applied to the new proposal? Where's that data?

Comment: @Walfrat - 40% of closure would have happened if gold tag badge holders had single vote closure. *Would* have, but did not. It is not just anyone.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - **We did not solve that problem**. Those statistics were for all closure, and all that was addressed was duplication. I find your insinuation and dismissal of closure problematic here. Gold tag badge holders are closing a very small percent of posts single-handedly at the moment. Clearly you have a biased opinion on the matter. In fact, this entire post is all your single opinion as it cites no reference nor statistical data.

Comment: @Travis: you're right. I mistook the statistics as focusing only on duplicates when they are for all possible closures. So, _at best_, they show a potential of a 10% improvement in the total closure rate, and since we _did_ solve this for the duplicate-closure scenario (at least, to the extent the proposed change would), some of that 10% has already been addressed. As for whether my post offers statistics or not, you're right it doesn't. As far as I'm concerned, the onus on providing the data is on the person who actually wants the change. So, show us the data.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think the 10% might be pessimistic. Consider that some who see closing currently as futile because too long and involved might actually do it a bit more, as well as many of the votes from those actually doing it being freed from reconfirming earlier votes...