# How are feature requests processed and discussed with the SE development and product design staff?

Tags: support, meta

I have asked for at least three medium, well-received feature requests here:

- [Establish a two stage question commit process?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289144/establish-a-two-stage-question-commit-process)
- [Would it be useful to have an extension of Mjölnir close voting powers for (language) tag related close reasons?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326250/would-it-be-useful-to-have-an-extension-of-mj%c3%b6lnir-close-voting-powers-for-lang)
- [Reward for close voters finding appropriate duplicates?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280568/reward-for-close-voters-finding-appropriate-duplicates)

And surely we can find [many upvoted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=votes) tagged with [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Is there some necessary threshold of (un-)popularity by voting getting it marked

- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Do site moderators communicate with the SE staff about popular feature requests?

The above mentioned tags always are added by a single moderator.

Who's going to set the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag, and for which criteria?

Is there some discussion applied/necessary involving other diamond moderators, or the SE staff (whatever departments apply to be responsible) before these tags are handed out?

How can I improve/bump my [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), getting involved in such process (if it exists at all)?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange

Comment: Moderators are site members like anyone else, and we can chat with SE employees in rooms where they appear. We can mention feature requests to them just as you can. All other avenues of communication are reserved for the rare things we can't take care of (vote invalidation, threats against users, database purging, etc.).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes, something like that. I've already been arguing with myself if this should be posted on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), but Stack Overflow has a particular status of popularity, and the need to discuss things with the staff might be more important than with other sites.

Comment: The core issue here is that your feature requests relate to a fundamental issue of what SO wants to be now that it is grown up, or what is its *raison d'être*. Although there are is some consensus around this question in its broad form, it is hardly fully-formed. There is a severe impedance mismatch among the stakeholders: owners of the site, who have a value system in which considerations of revenue/traffic/profitability/acquisition play at least some role; (2) veterans with a "get off my lawn" attitude; and (3) newbies who just want their answers now.

Comment: (cont'd) Until this mismatch is resolved to some extent, and I would not hold my breath, "feature requests" such as yours which actually are about changing the balance of power, especially if they involve any potential short-term risk to financial metrics, are unlikely to ever go anywhere.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The point of the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is so the community can suggest changes to any of the sites. We get tons of them across the entire network, some of them well-received, others not so much.

I can tell you that we (the SE staff) are always monitoring MSO/MSE and most of the other Meta sites for suggestions. Do we look for things more well-received than others (aka the popularity) of the request? Of course we do, but... proposing a feature and then getting it implemented are much different things.

I can only speak from my experience. If I see something that I think, "hey I like that idea", there are several steps to get it implemented; it's not as simple as poking a dev and asking them to do it. I'll spend time researching it, looking at data, figuring out possible implications, talking to others on the team, and then if we think it's feasible, writing it up. But writing it up still doesn't necessarily mean it will happen. I've asked for things and they get denied, or deferred due to lack of resources or it's a bigger project than we have time for right now.

I'd say most of the features have been seen by someone on the team, it's just not feasible for us to add a status-* tag to everything because they all take time to research, etc before making a final decision.

As far as adding a status- tag to a feature they are not based on popularity. We typically add them based on the following:

- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) is added when we know a particular request is not going to be implemented. It can be added immediately when a feature is just plain ridiculous or at a later time if we've investigated it and have decided we will not do it.
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) is added when we've either done some research but it's too much work at a specific time or it's in the plan for a later implementation.
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) is normally added to things that are being reviewed by staff (research, etc) to possibly implement or has already been written up and sent to the devs to implement   .

### Related

[Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange)

Comment: THX for the response. _"it's not as simple as poking a dev and asking them to do it"_ Surely not, that's why I mentioned the _design team_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Same thing, can't poke them... they don't like it

Comment: So for the mentioned status tags, what's the process used to hand them out? These are always used with a single handed edit of a particular moderator. Do moderators discuss before this happens, does a certain number has to agree? What means [tag:status-review]? That the feature request made it up to the SE staff and is considered for implementation?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've added a bit more on when the tags are used.

Comment: I've tried to improve my question as well in, the meantime. We're going to match pretty well right now.

Comment: Well, I can accept this answer. Though I'm curious what makes up the _populatity threshold_ triggering features to the SE staff. Is it upvotes, number of views?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There really isn't a threshold on this stuff, we're always _watching_ (probably over your shoulder) and then pick things to work on.

Comment: Is there any way to bump [tag:feature-request]s to your attention then (besides useless edts)? Not all of the mods might notice there was something interesting within their time being online?

Comment: _"probably over your shoulder"_ Huh, that's kinda frightening ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No way to bump it unless you useless edit it.

Comment: Well, I'll try to make _useful edits_ then, to bump the stuff (not right now, but after some contemplation about how to improve the requests). THX again for giving the insights.

Comment: related: [Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You can also put a bounty on it (if it's on MSE), which will also bump it and give it more visibility.

Comment: Perhaps we need more status tags? [tag:status-impossible], [tag:status-6to8weeks] or [tag:status-are-u-nuts]?

Comment: Or for questions we've asked for several times over the course of 5 years and the response is overwhelmingly positive, `status-poke-dev-now-please`