# Questions where the author is the problem

Tags: discussion, tags, close-reasons, meta

I have read all that I can find that relates to this topic, but I have been unable to discover a resolution, or anything that might relieve the frustration that I know I share with many other users

If anyone has a problem with me raising more than a single topic in one post, then I direct them to my final paragraph. Unfortunately you may need to read all that intervenes for the pronouns to make sense

Every day we see questions like

- [*Split a CSV file into three on the basis of the value in one of the columns*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002171/)
- [*launch program and execute command on program console from bash*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991166/)
- [*Length function on Perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983131/)

Those have been posted in only the last 24 hours, and only tagged for the Perl language

We are cornered into either providing a solution, together with a *huge* amount of advice and encouragement to find the answers themselves, or to pick an inappropriate **Stack Overflow** reason to close

The root of this sentiment appears to be [**bohemian's**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) [*Should we add a "Do my work for me" close reason?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/) from October 2014, which has received 430 upvotes and 18 downvotes. It has always been tagged with [`discussion`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) and [`close-reasons`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close-reasons)

I have tried to understand why this problem has always been ignored. I sense that those who frequent these pages are politically-minded, and it seems to me that perfectly valid requests or topics are often brushed aside just because, somehow, the request mustn't be discussed in its current state on the floor of the house. But that doesn't help me to understand why this concept has been repeatedly taken by the neck and drowned in the pond

There is a problem here, and too many people are forced to resolve it in their own way. I can't respect an authority that would rather turn a blind eye to what is essentially vigilante control, leaving that authority free to reprimand those who overreach while leaving the rest to police without the benefit of authorisation

Comment: i mean... we used to have a close reason that covered these, i'd suggest looking at why said close reason was removed. The current... *solution* if you can call it that is to simply cast a downvote. Unfortunately, that doesn't really work in practice because these easy to solve questions often get upvoted by answerers, whos answers also get upvoted due to being... "correct" thus drowning out any downvotes.

Comment: so.... I mean I get where you are coming from... but all these questions are currently on hold/closed ANYWAY.... what would bringing another close reason here would change?

Comment: @KevinB: That's one of many secondary reasons why it's a dreadful idea to allow such stuff. Dreadful questions engender dreadful answers.

Comment: @Patrice: It would at least give a warm feeling to those people who voted to close the questions for artificial reasons. It should also become part of the guidelines so that we have a reference when we kick people who ask how to print `Hello, World!`

Comment: Yup, and a -1 vote straight away, despite 6 upvotes for the commenters that agree.

Comment: @Borodin But they aren't artificial reasons.... one of them is too broad, WHICH IT IS. and the other 2 are the "debugging questions must include", which is also appropriate looking at the Qs... Again I get where you are coming from, but it's not like the current reasons are LACKING. Show me a question that cannot be put on hold with one of the current CV reasons, and that "do my work for me" would be able to close, and you will have an argument....

Comment: My gut feeling tells me you're not patient with beginner questions...and you want a reason to concisely punish them beyond what's already provided (which actually works alright, given that all of your examples *are* closed).

Comment: There aren't dupe target for these questions?

Comment: @Patrice: Imagine the reasons why they have been downvoted, and look at **bohemian's** post that I linked. Also imagine the question *how to print Hello, World!*. Not broad in any way, and there's no code to debug

Comment: have you read [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a “no comment” close reason for these?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)

Comment: @Borodin hmmm how to print has to be a dupe, so I again don't see a problem.... and in any case, a "How to" like that is still to broad IMHO, as there are a lot of ways to fix this issue.

Comment: @Makoto: I am a teacher, and love to help people to learn a programming language. I have no patience with those who copy code from the internet and bring it straight to me unmodified, asking why it doesn't work

Comment: That message was beyond well-received, but you're slightly dodging my point.  Given that by and large these are terrible beginner questions, they're all closed, and that the reasons for closure are appropriate, why do you feel the need to introduce something *more*?

Comment: @Patrice: You seem to be fighting hard for a reason for my question to be irrelevant. Believe me there are many instances every day when the problem is just that that OP doesn't know the language

Comment: @Borodin Provide an open question that "do my work for me" would close, and that the current reasons can't cover, and you have me convinced. I have already said so. I am not "fighting hard". You come here saying "We need a close reason for questions like these" but... they are ALL closed appropriately. So I fail to see the benefit of your close reason, not without a good example of where it should be used.

Comment: @Makoto: I don't believe the reasons were appropriate, and if you ask my peers they will also tell you that they feel guilt closing such questions on a false premise

Comment: @Patrice: I don't believe that any were closed appropriately. I want to leave this open for discussion, and within a day you may find people who will speak up for themselves. For what it's worth, no one has ever contended that the current categories were adequate. More extreme: "I'm a biochemist; how do I extract the 'ID' column from my colleague's 'XXBS2' SQLite database? It's not working."

Comment: @Borodin sorry dude... but we have a reason for "it's not working", and this is the perfect example for that. We need to code, the error message, and everything to work on that. See me as stubborn here... but I truly don't see how the current CV reasons don't fit these examples...

Comment: @Patrice: Please explain *we have a reason for "it's not working"* and *the current CV reasons*

Comment: Off-topic / No MCVE or Unclear if you only want to spend one-click.

Comment: I see an issue where those who answer the questions on Stack Overflow will usually not frequent ***meta***. Like me, they have little hope of being heard, and expect to be smacked down without reason. @Patrice, ***bohemian's*** post that I linked to explains precisely why a different example question doesn't fit any of the criteria. If you don't accept that then please just believe that I and several others have daily crises over how to treat a sloppy question that strictly falls outside any of the closure reasons.

Comment: @rene I don't understand you. It's very common that a poster doesn't understand what an MCVE is, and there is no applicable off-topic reason.

Comment: *despite 6 upvotes for the commenters that agree* - You can't down vote comments.

Comment: I always go with "Unclear what you're asking", simply because they haven't told us what they have done and why it isn't working.

Comment: There is a link in the off-topic reason to do help page what an MCVE is. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*

Comment: But I give you that if the author is really the problem then no text or link will  suffice.

Comment: A user not knowing or understanding what an MCVE is doesn't mean the close reason isn't applicable.

Comment: @Will Yes, i flit between various reasons. Too often none apply properly.

Comment: _I have tried to understand why this problem has always been ignored. I sense that those who frequent these pages are politically-minded_ Have you tried considering that people simply disagree with your assertions? I'm not politically invested in this topic and I disagree with you, so it can definitely happen. Having an opinion doesn't automatically make you right, remember

Comment: @Clive: I have looked at the people who frequent Meta, and was surprised to find that there are many who spend most of their time here. They appear to have built their reputation through site politics rather than software support, and much like real-life government they spend that reputation on maintaining the status quo. Take a look yourself; it's not hard to spot.

Comment: Build up reputation? If Meta rep counted as much as main site. But it does not.

Comment: So to clarify, if someone disagrees with you, they are like a real-life government, and only doing it to, I can only assume nefariously in your opinion, maintain a status quo? I know I'm reaching a bit there, but are you really going to just steamroll over everything else and tar every regular contributor to meta with the same lazy brush? Come on, engage in a real discussion, not "I'm right, why the hell don't you all agree with me? Must be politics". We're all better than that

Comment: @Clive: My concern is purely that the people who are influential on Meta are not the people who are influenced by their choices and decisions. More specifically, you will rarely see non-native English speakers representing their corner. That is a problem.

Comment: @RadLexus: It still appears to be a career choice for some.

Comment: @Clive: And it's far from *"I'm right ... anything"* but more like, *"Why aren't the opinions I see in my part of Exchange reflected here?"*. It takes only a handful of hardliners to downvote a post to oblivion, whereas I know one person who has quit SE, and several more who grumble but won't risk a roasting here. I don't think that's good. Do you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what your objection is to the specific questions you've called out, and certainly not enough to draw out a *general* problem, since I don't know beans about Perl. So I might be wrong here in the conclusions I'm going to attempt to draw, but I'm going to give it a shot anyway.

Yes, I think low-quality questions are a serious problem, and no, I don't think enough is being done about them. As Kevin B commented, there used to be a "lacks minimal understanding" close reason, but that got dropped along with an accusation that we were "misusing" it. I guess we lacked a minimal understanding of what that close reason was designed to be used for?

Anyway, since the "Summer of Love", we haven't had a good way of getting rid of questions like this. You can't flag them, because moderators will claim that this is something the community should handle on their own, even though we don't really have the tools or the scale to handle it. You can downvote them, but that doesn't make the problem go away—at least not soon enough. Eventually, it will lead to the source of these questions getting blocked from asking additional questions, but they can do plenty of damage to the community of experts assembled here in the meantime. In order to get enough downvotes for a ban to kick in, a *lot* of smart people have to waste their time reading the question, assessing its value, and expressing their evaluation with a downvote.

I think you should *continue* to downvote them, of course, but that isn't enough. We need a way to get rid of them. Fortunately, the ability to close questions hasn't been taken away from us altogether, so you will just need to apply a bit of creative thinking to the closure reasons that do exist. Here are the three you will want to use:

1. Off-topic because… "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."
2. "unclear what you're asking"
3. "too broad"

The bad questions that I believe you're describing, the ones where the author is the problem, are virtually always closable for one of these three reasons. If they're debugging questions, then you can close them for reason #1 because they lack an MCVE and/or a clear description of the problem. If they're more general questions, then you can close them as being "too broad" because an answer would need to be the length of a book or entire tutorial in order to cover all the necessary background information. Otherwise, they can be closed as "unclear" because they are.

This isn't ideal, since it still takes *at least* 5 highly-valued community members engaging with the question in order for it to be closed. [I've recently written at length](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342188/case-study-on-the-ignorance-or-refusal-to-use-moderation-privileges/342218#342218) about [better ways to deal with our current quality problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342216/366904), and that's hardly the first time it's been discussed or solutions have been proposed. So far, no evidence that anyone with the power to do something about this is listening. The site's overall quality is festering, and there is ample evidence that this is driving experts away, yet the focus has been on adding new features of questionable utility and redesigning the user interface, which is akin to rearranging the deck chairs on the Titanic post-iceberg.

Closing these types of questions as a duplicate will also work—sometimes. There are a couple of problems. First, finding a good duplicate target is hard and takes work. Second, it may not even be possible, since the problematic questions are often multiple questions in one, covering far too many bases to be answered adequately by a single duplicate. The upside, though, is that if you find a plausible duplicate, a gold tag badge holder can close the question as a duplicate immediately. This often makes it worth the effort to find a duplicate, and may even justify an "imperfect" duplicate closure.

As for the rest of your question—in particular the last two paragraphs—it reads a bit like an incoherent rant to me. Is "these pages" supposed to be Meta? What does it mean for someone to be "politically minded"? What specific "politics" do you think are at play here? And perhaps even more importantly, *what do* you *think the solution should be?* You haven't proposed one (maybe you did in the comments; I didn't read all of those).

The problem with a "do my work for me" close reason is, essentially, all good questions ask for someone to do work for the asker. That part is not what makes it a bad question. What makes it a bad question is it is vague, underspecified, incomplete, and/or would require an answer that is pages and pages long. Well, we do still have close reasons for these things. We just need to address the scale problem: the number of users with asking privileges vastly exceeds the number of users who have and exercise their moderation privileges, by at least two-fold.

Comment: The other problem with closing as a duplicate is that some questions are SO rudimentary there actually is no dup.