# Why is the close queue so much more full than other queues?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I realize that there have already been a number of similar questions about this, but it seems like most of the review queues (very low quality, triage, first post, etc.) are pretty short and are sometimes even empty (or close to empty). However, the Close queue has around 8,000 items in it or so. Does anyone have a definitive answer on why this is and if there are any immediate plans to address this?

Comment: *"any immediate plans to address this"* Why does it need to be addressed immediately? It's stable.

Comment: @Undo I'm not implying that it needs to be addressed immediately - it just seems like there have been a lot of proposals and I was just curious to see if any of them were going to be adapted.

Comment: @Undo If you consider the situation where most close votes age out because the queue is overfull "stable", then yeah... I guess it's stable... That doesn't mean we don't need to address it though.

Comment: I've personally found the Close Queue to be more "dangerous" to work in because of (what _I_ perceive to be) a much higher incidence of bad audits than in other queues.  I gave up looking at the close queue a long time ago and prefer to concentrate on Triage instead.

Comment: It's even fuller because there are plenty of questions with 1-3 close votes not even shown or ageing away. Not enough motivated reviewers and too many bad questions I guess.

Comment: I didn't even realise there was a close queue :\ I knew I could close questions at 3k, but didn't realise there was a queue (despite it making obvious sense now)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

tl;dr:

## Moar reviewers!

First, lets do some math. There are 40,769 users with close vote privileges, which have a potential capacity of doing reviews 1 630 760. This would allow to, assuming everything controversial (has 2 leave open and 4 close plus tie breaker), 232 965 potential questions to be dealt with. In other words, if everyone that reviews do so, all the current outstanding questions with pending reviews would have been decided (right now there are 8.8k), and we would have enough votes to deal with the 7.7k questions that are asked every day in average.

So, if there are enough users to make sure that the close queue is no more, why then the queue seems to never go down? Several potential explanations:

- Reviewer weariness: reviewers get tired of the constant stream of sub par questions. It gets so bad, that some can't keep their hope for humanity. A sane approach would be to keep reviewers in rotation, to make sure they don't lose motivation.
- Lack of knowledge: through the review queues have filters that allow you to review the topics you can do a sensible review about, this feature is (or I believe) underutilized. [Actual numbers are waiting for some virgins blood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322016/792066). [I suggested a way to fix this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254145/suggest-to-me-what-tag-filtering-i-should-use-in-review-next), pending of realization.
- Number aversion: is not the same that you ask 100k individual to clean 100km of beaches, than to ask 100 individuals to clean 1km. There are some that has aversions to big numbers that seems to not go down, and a lack of positive feedback seems to demotivate people with time. I proposed a way to present [this feedback back to reviewers](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=3560717#3560717), it seems to [be something of sorts in the works](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3560860#3560860).
- The above leads to <s>technical</s> community moderation debt, which reinforces part of the cycle.
- Overgamification: reviewers tend to stop reviewing once they acquire certain extrinsic motivators (aka badges).
- Lack of desire that others moderate: there is a group of user that believes that any act of moderation is a waste of time, which by itself it's fine, but there has been cases where this group boycotts the other users moderating task, which contributes with the weariness of the users doing the actual moderation.

This is mostly a very biased interpretation of the current affairs. I think I haven't missed important variables at play, but if you feel I did, feel free to add it with the references.

Comment: This one is kinda obvious omission but since I don't have a good way to measure it, I presumed that everyone that is capable of reviewing is active and engaged with the site, but this isn't true.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that questions enter the queue using flags and no close vote are done outside of the queue, but since you always are left with 10 extra close votes, such effect can be ignored.

Comment: Note that no one is obligated to use their close votes, and its OK to not want to. The fact of the matter is that there is always going to be a large portion of the user base that doesn't want to use their moderation privileges for various reasons. It doesn't have to be about thinking it is a waste of time.

Comment: @TinyGiant considering that since we only need ~3% of users to leverage their privileges, we could strike some sort of deal, don't you agree? It could be just 1 review every odd day.

Comment: Speaking for myself, I find working through the queue a pretty time consuming experience. For about 75% of the review items I need way more context so I have to go look at the question, its answers and its comments. On top of that I find being able to see other close review choices misleading as I'm not going to blindly follow them and have to reason if I agree with them or not. More often than not, I just don't have the time.

Comment: @Gimby you might find more reasonable to use the filters. For example: I filter by [debian] and off topic, which is easily to determine, since Debian is an OS, and people tend to ask general computing questions with that tag, so I can just rush through the queue. Try that. Find a tag you are familiar with and filter by the most easily identifiable problem, you will find the experience more rewarding.

Comment: @Braiam good advice, I will do that eventually when I'm good at the game, right now I'm a close-voter-in-training :)

Comment: In addition to all of this, the fact that you can review a max number per day means that on a day when you'd be willing to set aside some time to do it, you still have minimal impact.

Comment: I'm active-**ish**... but the review queues are not for me.

Comment: Incentivize users to clear the CV queue with SO swag. I know I'd definitely participate in the CV queue more if this was the case.

Comment: @DanielStorm actually, that's the kind of solution we don't want. Instead of reviewing because you care about the quality of the questions on SO, you care about obtaining a reward.

Comment: Excellent break-down of why the close queue is so high, but not for why it's so high *in comparison to the other queues*.

Comment: @Mooz If you read the list of points, it perfectly describes why others queues doesn't suffer the same fate as the close queue. Basically, other than gamification, the other queues doesn't require of the reviewer with the same intensity as the close queue does.

Answer (score 21):

The close vote review queue is really big because users are inherently good at asking bad questions.

There are currently—and have been—many plans on how to deal with this, with varying levels of immediacy, popularity, and efficiency. There is even at least one chat room centered around reviewing in the close vote queue.

One example of a plan: [Let's burn down the close queue!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue?rq=1)

Comment: Right, but the linked post is from 2014 and the review queue still has around 8,000 posts in it.

Comment: People keep asking bad questions, and other people keep flagging them and voting to close them, it's a vicious cycle. It had more than 10k, the other day, and I've seen it around 6k in recent history.

Comment: People being good at asking bad questions doesn't explain why the close-vote queue is larger than the other queues that address bad questions. Perhaps the difference is more that there are fewer users with privileges to deal with these, and it takes 5 of them.

Comment: @CodyGray the last time I checked there were plenty of users with privileges but for some reasons only a very small subset of those users really leverage their moderation privileges. Anything that helps to turn in-active > 3K-ers into active close voters will resolve the *issue*, if we assume it is an issue that needs solving.

Comment: @Cody That depends on whether you perceive the large number to a be a problem. The large number itself isn't the problem. The only problem is questions not getting closed in a timely manner if at all, which is caused by  a combination of many factors. There is no concrete evidence to say that any one factor has any more impact than any other factor, and I would say it is beyond the scope of this question to elaborate the intricacies of the close vote system

Comment: The large number is a symptom of the exact thing we agree is a problem: "questions not getting closed in a timely manner if at all". I don't think that discussing the intricacies of the system is "beyond the scope of this question" at all. In fact, it is exactly what the question is asking!

Comment: @Cody the number could just as easily be smaller if people *stopped* flagging and voting to close questions. The number is the size that it is because the system is working. Some things don't get closed in a timely manner if at all, and many other things do get closed in a timely manner. The system isn't perfect, but it does work. The question here asks for a definitive answer of why the number is big, and if there are any plans to do something about the size of the number. I believe my answer reasonably answers the question.

Comment: On the gripping hand: the average time to close on question is 7 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

The number of open questions with at least one close vote is even higher than the displayed size of the close vote queue. The system [prunes the queue and refills it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252584/839601) automatically. So even if you could drain it, it would take some time before you'd see an effect.

However, it's probably not drained but rather filled so that many close-worthy questions stay open because the close voting process cannot be finished. The system discards some (many?) of the total casted close votes with time.

Being voluntary, the reviewers who can and want to vote probably cannot do all the reviewing work that needs to be done in order to process the large amount of closeable questions we get every day. Effectively some close-worthy questions remain open and some close votes have no effect.

We experimented with [increasing the number of close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science). Quoting from the [results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/1536976):

> We need to do something about the close votes... we'll start looking at increasing the number of close votes based on rep.

We gave gold badge owners an immediate right to close duplicates in their corresponding tag (the duplicate hammer).

We also proposed to improve question quality [before they are asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342060/fixing-the-no-sample-input-no-expected-output-and-show-us-your-code-proble) by smart (rep thresholded) info/warning messages.

However, being a voluntary service, I see the fundamental issue that reviewing capacity might just not be sufficient.

Reviewing bad questions is less fun than answering good questions. This seems to be especially true for close vote reviewing.

Now if every asker would pay only a single dollar per question which is then paid out to the reviewers according to their reviewing time...

Comment: *"We gave gold badge owners an immediate closing right in their corresponding tag"* Only for duplicates. :'(

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for pointing it out. I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: prune-and-refill reference is here: [Enough fuzzying: let's let everything into the close queue and age out questions that don't reach a threshold](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252584/839601)