# Display a popup when a low-reputation user tags a question with a frequently-misused tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

*Very* closely related: [How should we deal with people misusing the [Visual-Studio] and [Android-Studio] tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346150/how-to-deal-with-people-misusing-the-visual-studio-and-android-studio-tags)

To repeat the context from the linked post, here's the description of the [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) tag:

> Visual Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE) from Microsoft. **Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality, not just a question regarding your code.** Consider tagging the exact technology area your question links to and also tagging a more specific version of Visual Studio. Please mention your exact VS version, edition, and update level in your question.

There's a similar disclaimer for the [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) tag:

> Use for questions about using Android Studio, an official IDE targeted at Android development. **Do NOT use for questions about programming for Android in general**; instead use [android].

And yet, as discussed on the linked question, the tag is routinely misused (mostly by low-reputation users), which tends to diminish the value of the tag for people who are actually asking tool-related questions.

One idea thrown about there would be to create a popup describing the proper use of these tags; I'd like to suggest that as a site feature. This would happen only for low-reputation users and/or the first time that someone used one of these tags.

There's no need to include this kind of message for every single tag, obviously, just ones that are routinely misused.

**Edit:** This is already being done for several tags. For example, when you go to tag a question as a [burniation-request] on Meta, the following happens:
[image]

For the record, it *actually worked* - when I saw that, I *did*, in fact, read the Meta post it links to.

**Second edit:** There are certain tags, such as [vpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vpn), [openvpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openvpn), [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo), and a few others that seem to draw a *lot* of off-topic questions. This is true in spite of the fact that the tag usage guidelines for these often explicitly warns people against misuse. For example, almost all of the questions tagged [openvpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openvpn) are off-topic (the tag is [currently subject to a cleanup request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350408/close-the-openvpn-tag-or-at-least-clean-it-up)), even after the tag usage guideline was updated to state that this tag should be used for programming questions, not for questions on configuring or using VPNs. Point being that people - especially new users - don't seem to read the tag usage guidance too carefully (if at all).

Implementing this feature could help reduce the volume of off-topic questions, which could reduce the [overfilling of the close queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342457/why-is-the-close-queue-so-much-more-full-than-other-queues) (among other benefits).

Comment: [tag:xcode], [tag:iphone], [tag:ibm], ...

Comment: _There's no need to include this kind of message for every single tag_ - I wouldn't count on that, though.

Comment: I would want to limit it to new users though.  Maybe < 200 rep or some other threshold.

Comment: If you look at how often stack snippets are abused for _any_ kind of code, how often `[java]` and `[javascript]` are used in the place of the other, how often tags are used whose description starts with `DO NOT USE!` (e.g. `[api]`) and (before it was nuked from orbit) people would use `[bootstrap]` for any one of the dozen different things that had "bootstrap" in their name, I would argue that the people who currently misuse all these things won't be bothered by a popup. I sadly do not have a better proposal, but I'm pretty sure the requested feature would be rather futile.

Comment: I like the idea, but I think people ignore/dismiss popups. To make it work, we should let them take a multiple-choice test, to see if they know what an IDE is. That, however, is at odds with Stack Exchange philosophy.

Comment: The problem seems to be that people don't read the tag wikis, which _do_ pop up when adding tags. For some reason they feel like they don't need to read it. I agree with Siguza, if you really want to get people's attention, you could edit their question and then confront them (in a comment) with what they did wrong.

Comment: Now that I've tested it; part of the problem might be that tag wikis are not accessible (e.g. by hovering over the tag) after selecting a tag. To review the wiki you'd have to remove the tag, attempt to add it again, and then in the suggestions bar, read the tag wiki. People start to type a tag they have in mind, see the tag pop up in the suggestions, think "hey that's the one I want" and click it. They never read the tag wiki, because it doesn't stay up long enough, and hovering over the tag doesn't bring it up again.

Comment: @JornVernee That problem happens both when asking and when editing questions. If you'd make a feature-request (preferably on MSE) to show tag wikis excerpts after using them, I'd upvote it. It _might_ just save us from a few attempts to add "DO NOT USE" tags to questions.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Looks like it already exists :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201587/make-tag-popups-display-permanently-while-editing (although it was asked over 3 years ago :/)

Comment: @JornVernee Oh, I missed that... voted it up now, thanks!

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/213575 @JornVernee  "The problem seems to be that people don't read the tag wikis, which do pop up when adding tags" maybe because the system is the one that suggest them.

Comment: _"just ones that are routinely misused"_ -- if we're getting into the business of classifying tags, I think a) the pop-up needs to be much more dramatic than the little fly-out that shows up for tags now, and b) the idea should be extended to being able to mark tags as mutually exclusive with each other (the imposing pop-up would require the user to confirm e.g. they really want to post a question that includes [tag:java], [tag:c#], and [tag:c++]), and tags that should not be used (e.g. the description starts with the text "DO NOT USE").

Comment: @PeterDuniho Good point (could actually possibly be an answer). In fact, if the tag is marked with "do not use," should the site even *allow* them to be used in the first place?

Comment: _"should the site even allow them to be used in the first place?"_ -- for better or worse, I think probably so. Only if a diamond mod has the ability to mark a tag as prohibited (do they? I'm not aware of that feature), and has done so, should a user be outright prohibited from using a tag. Otherwise, shenanigans with user edits to tags have more impact than they should. But I'm all in favor of putting up a big warning to users who the system has good reason to believe are about to do something wrong.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for a pop up, more guidance in general may help though.

Comment: @Siguza Oh god, if we could fix people using snippets for any kind of code, I would be so happy. I've have to un-snip-ify C# code pretty much every other day (sometimes it's tagged JS and sometimes CSS, I still have no idea what makes someone think "Oh, I'll put it in CSS I guess").  The same sort of people who *don't look at the god damn preview* I'm sure. <Shakes a fish at the people who can't be arsed to indent their code with ctrl-k>

Comment: @Draco18s I feel you, mate... I always imagine that's the same group of people who also mix spaces and tabs for indentation, dip their chips in water and eat their KitKat's sideways.

Comment: @Siguza What kind of psychopath *eats a KitKat sideways!?*

Comment: @Draco18s Idk, [a lot of people](https://www.google.ch/search?q=kitkat+sideways&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisxpKehtLUAhWCtxoKHSL2DKEQ_AUICigB&biw=2560&bih=1239#q=kitkat+sideways&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CUFWwnkSDsNrIjgfIm6CUKoIPPcw2RSQcumKtokCNawFw2oUbVnV-_1gvwwzE_1anoc8RycG6qSUa6wWiHR9N-IZJXSSoSCR8iboJQqgg8EZHf2ABZ47V3KhIJ9zDZFJBy6YoRH2Wt4Kqj6CIqEgm2iQI1rAXDahHHdwDkR5TnkSoSCRRtWdX7-C_1DEYkwOZF_1M0L4KhIJDMT9qehzxHIRejsEG5V9-3IqEglwbqpJRrrBaBH-QkpL-BYAFSoSCYdH034hkldJEZFS7wchWeMX), it seems...

Comment: @Siguza Those...those MONSTERS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am in favor of *some* kind of additional guidance for users regarding tag usage. But I think it needs to be more context-sensitive. Even for low-reputation users, I'm not sure we want or need to be impeding them with a pop-up *solely* because they included e.g. the [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) tag.

I'm not sure what the context would be for that particular tag, actually. It may be hard to distinguish in a reliably way valid uses of the tag from invalid ones. But there are other tags that are nominally mutually exclusive. I'm thinking of e.g. language tags, like [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift), [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), etc. While not impossible, it is rare for a question to actually be *about* more than one programming language at a time. It would be useful, I think, to present *all* users (not just low-reputation ones) with a large pop-up when they attempt to add a second tag mutually-exclusive with one that's already been added, requiring them to confirm that they meant to do that and that the combination is in fact appropriate.

It's possible this approach would even work with [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio). Looking at the newest 50 question so tagged, I see a couple that are obviously mis-tagged. One includes [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays), [matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrix), and [multidimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array), all of which, being language features and not IDE features, seem like candidates for being mutually exclusive with [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio). Another includes [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string), another potential candidate. (Of course, a third includes *no* relevant tags other than a language tag, and so would still slip through…oh well, no rule is going to be perfect.)

To this logic, we could also include tags whose description begins with "DO NOT USE". We might even disallow the use of JavaScript code snippets unless the question is tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Again, it won't be possible to do this in a way that catches *all* misuses of tags. And some users will always ignore whatever pop-up you display for them. But I would hope and expect that a system with this sort of cross-checking could address a significant amount of the inappropriate tagging, and would help keep the tag feeds more tidy.

Comment: The tag-exclusivity feature request was something I thought of for another reason.  Nothing ever came of it when asked ([Stop users from tagging SSE and Server-Sent-Events in the same question, and warn for SSE + JS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390150)) except for comments that SE inc was unlikely to add back-end support for it.

Answer (score 8):

Turning my comment into an answer, I think the feature you're requesting won't help. There are a lot of things that people misuse:

- Tags whose description starts with "DO NOT USE" (e.g. [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api)).
- Tags that mean something else (prime example: [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) vs [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript))
- Stack snippets - they're used for all and any kinds of code.
- Formatting - how often do you see code not indented at all, or marked up with backticks instead?

These all provide evidence that there is a certain group of users, commonly low-rep, who cannot be bothered to read *anything*. Be that the help centre, the markup guide, the tag description, the preview of their own post, *anything*. There may be an arbitrary number of low-rep users who are doing everything right, but I'm pretty sure that the group we've isolated here will hardly be bothered by any kind of warning or popup.

The way I see it, we have two options when dealing with misused features:

- We make them inaccessible to the group that most frequently misuses them.
- We accept the misuse, prepare to do a lot of edits, and possibly train [a bot](https://github.com/SOBotics) to detect and report misuse.

The question is whether we want to act in good or bad faith.

Comment: I suppose we *could* force them to read somehow... maybe force them to read the Tour page before they can use the tags at all?

Comment: @EJoshuaS How would you go about implementing that? All common implementations that I know of (timeout, scroll to bottom) don't actually ensure that the user has read anything whatsoever. They could also do that years before asking their first questions and forget what they read. Plus we'd also have to make sure they read, understand and respect tag descriptions, which doesn't necessarily follow from reading the tour page.