# Close the OpenVPN tag (or, at least, clean it up)

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, clean-up

The tag description of [openvpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openvpn):

> Free software implementing virtual private networks (VPN). Uses TCP or UDP, not IPSec.

The vast majority of the questions I've seen there are off-topic (they should be on Super User or Server Fault).

Can this tag be burned (or, at least, cleaned up)?

As Cato the Elder famously [said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthago_delenda_est), [openvpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openvpn) delenda est!

**Edit:** I've put a fair number of them on the close vote review queue, if anyone can spare some close votes to filter on that tag in the review queue I'd definitely appreciate it.

Comment: Practically zero Questions are about programming with OpenVPN, I agree that something needs to be done with this tag.  What happens to the few programming-oriented OpenVPN questions if the tag is closed, though?

Comment: @Graham We'd probably just want to re-tag the ones that are reasonable questions.

Comment: I'm happy to help.  Maybe the new tag should be openvpn-api?

Comment: [tag:vpn] and [tag:pptp] are in the same boat. There are a _few_ questions about implementing VPN software, but the vast majority of questions in those tags are about configuring or using VPNs.

Comment: @Graham Good question, I'm not sure

Comment: @duskwuff We should burn them too

Comment: We should also have clear guidelines as to the decision between SuperUser or ServerFault.  I can see how individual posts should be redirected to one or the other but a blanket rule probably wouldn't work..

Comment: @Graham That's true - it seems a little ambiguous even from their respective help centers at points which questions should be directed where (in particular for networking questions). They seem to prefer that home desktop/networking questions go to Super User and corporate IT questions go to Server Fault, but it seems a bit fuzzy to me.

Comment: There are 2027 questions tagged openvpn on serverfault, 1061 on superuser.  Who knows how many are duplicates on each site, let alone between them? (rhetorical question)

Answer (score -11):

There are a significant number of questions floating around on SO from the olden days before SU and SF were developed that are very clearly no longer on topic. As far as I'm aware, there hasn't been a consensus for going on a generalized question-burning expedition, and I don't see a good reason why "historical" questions should have relevant metadata stripped.

(I do think there's a good case to be made for a generalized cleanup and locking grandfathered OT questions, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: SU came about '08, earliest openvpn question on SO is '08. From '08 to '10 there are less than 9 questions. The overwhelming majority of these questions do not predate the existence of SU.