# Gold badges for review tasks should confer extra close votes

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I originally suggested this idea in an answer to this question: [We need more close votes!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes)

Also related: [Why is the close queue so much more full than other queues?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342457/why-is-the-close-queue-so-much-more-full-than-other-queues)

My other proposal on the topic of close votes (to reduce the number of close votes required to close a question): [Reduce the number of votes required to close a question to 4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4)

I do realize that there have been multiple proposals to give people more close votes. I would like to propose a variant on this: give people who hold gold badges for review tasks more close votes (as long as at least one of the gold badges is for the close vote queue).

I think 5 extra votes per gold badge would be a good number (so, for example, if you had gold badges in the Close Vote, Edit, and VLQ review queues you'd have an extra 15 votes).

Comment: While I'm not unsympathetic against these kind of proposals, do know that a very low number of users actually hit the daily limit on a regular basis. So this would only benefit maybe a handful users and with that have probably no noticeable effect on the number of closures nor on the size of the queue. At best it is seen as a reward by the  steward badge holders.

Comment: The problem with queues is breadth (spreading the load over more reviewers), not depth. This is the wrong way to fix things.

Comment: I don't want to review more, I want to review more effectively.

Comment: @rene,  the current behavior is designed to punish people who take a genuine interest in the site.  The quote should be proportion to the total amount of review possible.  I.E (8 Queues - 1 (Reopen Queue) * (40 max number of votes possible in the queue))/ percentage of questions which pass review on average